# I can't call a function that I've assigned to an element in React

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

App.jsx
`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ToDoItem from "./ToDoItem";

function App() {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    setInputText(newValue);
  }

  function addItem() {
    setItems((prevItems) => {
      return [...prevItems, inputText];
    });
    setInputText("");
  }

  function deleteItem() {
    console.log("item called delete.");
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="heading">
        <h1>To-Do List</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="form">
        <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" value={inputText} />
        <button onClick={addItem}>
          <span>Add</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {items.map((todoItem) => (
            <ToDoItem
              key={items.toString()}
              text={todoItem}
              onChecked={deleteItem}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`

ToDoItem.jsx
`

```
import React from "react";

function ToDoItem(props) {
  return <li onClick={props.onCheked}>{props.text}</li>;
}

export default ToDoItem;
```

`

①I'm trying to call the 'deleteItem' function when the elements are clicked. I'm checking this with a console.log inside the function. However it never works when I click on the element.

②When I clicked on the element, there were a warning appearing in the console:
[Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiYzM.png)
So I checked in the React document and added `key={items.toString()}` . But When I added the second item in the list, there appeared another warning:
[Warning: Encountered two children with the same key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCAWJ.png)

I wonder how I can solve these two problems. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

① Do you have some errors in the console?

② When you call `key={items.toString()}` the key will have the same value for each child because you refer to the item list. Try to add an id in `ToDoItem` and use it for the key `key={todoItem.id}` or more easily `key={todoItem.toString()}` (but with the last one you can't have two items with the same text)

Comment: Thanks!
①There are no errors, which makes me really confused
②The second one works for me. And I found key={todoItem} also works

Comment: Ah, now the console.log works. Although I do not change code...confused